# Secrecy of bibtex direcory location

Tags: bibtex

I am using bibtex for references and have a link to the directory in the .tex file. This directory makes it obvious for whom te project is done, but this should remain secret (academic assignment at a corporation that wants to remain anonymous). Are these directories anywhere to be found in the final pdf? In other words, if the visible text in the pdf does not reveal anything, is it possible to get it out of the source? Of course the .tex will not be published. If it is anywhere in the pdf, how do i get it out?

Comment: it isn't in the pdf but if it concerns you at all why not just copy the tex and .bib files to /tmp/zzzz before starting, and run latex and bibtex in the zzzz directory? You shouldn't anyway need to put the path to the bib file in your tex source as long as it is in the system BIBINPUTS path, but if you put it in the current directory there is no issue at all.

Comment: Thanks, no need to worry! I have my .bib located in another folder because i use it for multiple tex files. Just to be sure I probably will move it to a temp folder for the typesetting of the final pdf.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't in the pdf but if it concerns you at all why not just copy the tex and .bib files to `/tmp/zzzz` before starting, and run latex and bibtex in the `zzzz` directory? You shouldn't anyway need to put the path to the bib file in your tex source as long as it is in the system `BIBINPUTS` path, but if you put it in the current directory there is no issue at all.